# How to trigger the java agent from xpage button click event?

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

I'd like to test java agent to clear all the documents in a view by triggering the button click event on my xpage. I have no errors in java agent, but it is not working. Could you help me out to get through this stage?

*Button click event:*

```
var serverName=session.getCurrentDatabase().getServer();
//@WarningMessage("current one");
//@WarningMessage("server=" + serverName);
//var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(session.getCurrentDatabase().getServer(), "\ProTexII.nsf");
var db:NotesDatabase=session.getCurrentDatabase();
@WarningMessage("db=" + db);

var agent:NotesAgent = db.getAgent("SnapShotUpdate");
@WarningMessage("agent" + agent);

if (agent!=null){

 agent.run();
 @WarningMessage("view is fired!");

}
```

*Java agent:*

```
package javaPkg;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import lotus.domino.*;

public class SnapShotUpdate extends AgentBase{

 public void NotesMain() {
       try {

         //String p = session.getPlatform();
           //PrintWriter out=getAgentOutput();

          System.out.println("Hello i never give it up!!");


          Session session = getSession();
          AgentContext agentContext =session.getAgentContext();
          Database db=session.getCurrentDatabase();


          //**clear view "vActualSalesFromSD" before copying documents into it

          DocumentCollection dc= db.createDocumentCollection();
          View view= db.getView("vActualSalesFromSD");
          Document docToBeCleared= view.getFirstDocument();

          while (docToBeCleared != null) {

             {
                dc.addDocument(docToBeCleared);
             }

                docToBeCleared = view.getNextDocument(docToBeCleared);
          }

          dc.removeAll(true);
       } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }


}
```

Comment: Any warningmessage fired? You could also use database.getAgent() directly since object database is always present. Same goes for session.

Comment: Do you have plans to make this agent more complex later? In its current form, this is a fairly simple operation... you might as well just run this code directly in the button event. If the only reason you're calling an agent is so that the document removal will occur under the signer's permissions, use sessionAsSigner to get a separate handle on the current database; anything you do within the database via that handle will be done as the signer, not the user.

Comment: P.S. If the goal is specifically to delete all documents from a given view, don't bother looping: db.getView("vActualSalesFromSD").getAllEntries().removeAll(true) will achieve the same result.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to wrtie and test java agent because I don't get familiar with lotus script. This agent would be complex later and it'd be changed as an scheduled agent. Thank all of you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

You have 3 possibilities to trigger your code:

1. The approach you have taken
2. Make an ajax call to /yourdatabase.nsf/SnapshotUpdate?OpenAgent
3. Don't use an agent (**highly**) recommended -> it is Java already, use a class and call it in your SSJS

What can go wrong:

1. The agent has a target other than "none"
2. You don't have delete rights in that database
3. You don't have the right to run the agent (not very likely, since you can run a XPage)

I would write the loop like this:

```
  public function clearView(Database db, String vName ) {
     try {
         View view= db.getView("vActualSalesFromSD");
         Document docToBeCleared= view.getFirstDocument();
         Document nextDoc = null;

         while (docToBeCleared != null) {
            nextDoc = view.getNextDocument(docToBeCleared);
            try {
                 docToBeCleared.remove(true);
                } catch (Exception didntWork) {
                // Do some logging here
                }
            // Recycle your objects
            doc.recycle();
            docToBeCleared = nextDoc;             
         }

        // cleanup, we recycle what we opened, but not the parameters
        // nextDoc and docToBeCleared are null already;
        v.recycle();

     } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

Let us know you progress.

Comment: Now my agent is running. The thing is when i create new agent, one java agent is automatically created under Src/(default package), but I created new java class as an agent under separate package instead and tried calling it from my xpage. Thanks it was solved :)

Comment: You still shouldn't use an agent here - unless you can share a good reason